# Mex class memory leak - Is a destructor needed with STL maps?

Tags: c++, matlab, memory-leaks, destructor, mex

I am searching for a memory leak in some mex code (IT support where I'm working haven't installed the useful debug flags, making Valgrind next to useless...).

One of the potential sources I've found is my home-made Matrix class. It uses an STL map of maps (i.e. `map<int, map<int, double> >` to store the matrix. I had assumed that thanks to my use of the STL, C++ could automagically handle the garbage collection at the end of the program execution, but I'm now wondering, do I need to hard-code the destructor to clear out first the inner maps then the outer one?

The only other instance variables are a couple of ints, so I don't see those causing any problems.

For clarity, the relevant parts of the Matrix class definition:

```
class Matrix
{
    public:
        std::map< int, std::map<int, double> > elems;
        int rows;
        int cols;

        Matrix( );
        Matrix( int numRows, int numCols );

        // ... Getters, setters, operations and other miscellanea
}
```

(I realise declaring my instance vars as public is sloppy OO practice, but that's hacky research code for you!).

If it's not the destructor, I'm wondering if it's somewhere in the following code:

```
    Matrix D;
    distance_cost( &D, &traj1, &traj2 ); // Init Matrix and flesh out data
    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( D.rows, D.cols, mxREAL ); // Prepare output
    D_output = mxGetPr( plhs[1] );
    D.toDouble( D_output ); // Convert Matrix data maps to double* for Matlab
```

where `distance_cost` is defined thusly:

```
void distance_cost( Matrix *Q, Trajectory *A, Trajectory *B) {

    int M = A->length( );
    int N = B->length( );

    (*Q) = Matrix( M, N );

    for( int m=0; m < M; m++ ) {
        for( int n=0; n < N; n++ ) {
            float dist = A->at(m).dist2D( B->at(n) );
            Q->set(m,n,dist);
        }
    }

}
```

and `toDouble()` is:

```
void Matrix::toDouble( double *dbl ) const {
    for( int i=0; i < this->rows; i++ ) {
        for( int j=0; j < this->cols; j++ ) {
            dbl[i+j*this->rows] = this->at(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help, advice or criticism on my sloppy use of memory management is welcomed - I've hacked myself into quite the quagmire and can't really work out how to get out of it!

Comment: How do you know the MEX file is leaking memory? And do you have any global variables within the MEX file? Also, `distance_cost` should really be taking references to those parameters instead of pointers. `Q` should be `Matrix&`, while the other two should be `Trajectory const&`.

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything, compiler will generate all the destructor calls automatically

Comment: @Praetorian, when I comment the call to that mex function out of the code, my memory usage stays fairly constant (I replaced the output with some blank matrices to check). If it's enabled, I burn through memory, then page file then Matlab dies... (It gets called a few hundred thousand times).

Comment: @aleguna, thanks that's what I was presuming.

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign the output matrix to `plhs[1]` and not `plhs[0]`; even though MATLAB has 1-based indexing, you're writing C or C++ in MEX files, so the indexing is 0-based. Also, your comment about converting data to `double *` for MATLAB is bothersome. `mxGetPr` returns a `real_T *` to the memory you allocated via the `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` call. The size of this memory area is `rows * cols`. You should only be copying data from your `Matrix` class to this area, not allocating anything. Remember that MATALB expects the matrix to be stored column-major.

Comment: Ah, there's another output before this at plhs[0], but that doesn't seem to be causing the problem. Regarding the conversion, I believe I'm actually doing what you suggest - I allocate the space using `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`, then in `.toDouble( )` I loop through my `Matrix` map rows, inserting data at the relevant indices. If I'm not doing that correctly, please do correct me.

Comment: you can only have a memory leak if you have a `new` without a delete in your code. From what i've seen you look good.

Comment: That sounds like the right thing to do. If you don't have any `new` / `malloc` / `mxMalloc` calls in your code, the only other suspects would be `mxCreate*` and other MATLAB API functions that allocate memory. If you're calling these, you should be deallocating the memory manually, unless they are output parameters and you're assigning the variables to `plhs`. Also, make sure you set `nlhs` correctly, otherwise MATLAB will not know how many return values there are.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help - I can't see anything obvious, but I'll keep hunting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are all of the member variables in `Matrix`, then you are very likely fine.

- `std::map< int, std::map<int, double> > elems;`
- `int rows;`
- `int cols;`

It's always possible that a particular function is leaking memory. But from what you've shown us, you won't leak any memory.

Comment: Yes they are, thanks - I thought as much, but I'm getting desperate!

Comment: Regarding your edit, I thought you *shouldn't* call destroy array for any arrays being used as output. It was in the bullet list here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/troubleshooting-mex-files.html#f24804

Unless I've misinterpreted it?

Comment: No, he doesn't need to call `mxDestroyArray`! The matrix is an output parameter from the MEX file, MATLAB will take care of destroying it.